# Python3 Tkinter, how do I get a variable inside of a def?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get the variable "user_get" inside the def entered(user_input)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()


#put settings in place (username input)
window.geometry('1920x1080')
window.configure(bg = 'blue')

def entered(user_input):
    user_get = user_input.widget.get()
    user_input.widget.delete(0, 'end')
    print(user_get)
    return user_get
    user_input.widget.destroy()



# TextBox (input)
user_input = tk.Entry(window)
user_input.pack()
user_input.place(x = 100,y = 40)
user_input.bind("<Return>", entered) 



thing = user_get
print(thing)

window.mainloop()
```

I have tried:

-return (I don't really understand it that well)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the value of `user_get`? Also, a few notes: **1.** the code after the `return` statement will *never* run because the function is done once it hits a `return`, **2.** the value *return*ed by `entered` isn't being used anywhere, **3.** there's no point in clearing the `user_input` text if you're just going to `destroy` the widget, **4.** you don't need `user_input.widget.destroy()` - just `user_input.destroy` should work, and **5.** `thing = user_get` will always equal `None` since `user_get` only exists inside the scope of the `entered` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've made it so the `user_input` variable is available in the global scope. The `global` keyword in the `entered` function allows that function to modify the global variable. Now, when you type into the entry and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, the value of `user_input` is updated.

I defined an example function that will print this value whenever a button is pressed. Note that until you add text to the `Entry` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>, an empty string will be printed!

Likewise, any calls like `print(user_input)` made immediately before `root.mainloop()` will print an empty string because the value of `user_input` hasn't been updated yet.

```
import tkinter as tk


def entered(_event):
    global user_input  # allow this function to modify this variable
    user_input = entry.get()  # update the variable with the entry text
    entry.delete(0, 'end')  # clear entry contents


def use_value_from_entry():
    """Example function to use the value stored in 'user_input'"""
    print(user_input)
    


window = tk.Tk()

user_input = ''  # create a variable to store user input in the global scope
entry = tk.Entry(window)  # create the entry widget
entry.pack()  # add the widget to the UI
entry.bind('<Return>', entered)  # bind the event handler

# this button runs an example function to get the current value of 'user_input'
button = tk.Button(window, text='Click Me', command=use_value_from_entry)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()  # run the app

#Stockmage updated this
```

Comment: If this answer works out for you, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark button (that way others know this question has been answered). Otherwise, just let me know if you have any questions or run into any issues!

Comment: but I'm not trying to get rid of the textbox, I'm actually just clearing when there is an input. what i'm trying to do is to get the entry_value.

Comment: into a variable

Comment: Okay, I'll fix that - I wasn't sure, since your original code destroyed the `Entry` widget.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry for not clarifying. (I made this script as a demonstration so I removed a lot of the original parts, the clearing of the textbox was left over from another piece of the code)

Comment: Heads up: my answer had an unnecessary binding to `textvariable` on the `Entry` widget - you can go ahead and remove that!

Comment: ik, I fixed it (thx for the heads up tho)